# React-Select custom options array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use `react-select`, https://react-select.com/, and the mandatory format for the `options` prop seems to be `{value:something, label:something}`.

I have a list of objects with other key,value pairs and **my question is if there is any workaround for me `not having to modify the array`** because if i modify it, it means that the `select component` will not return an object of the initial array so i will have to map them again.

```
options = [
    {name: 'opt1', descr:'descr1'},
    {name: 'opt2', descr:'descr2'},
    {name: 'opt3', descr:'descr3'},
]
```

In `Vue` i get to choose the `key` that will be used as `label`, for example.

> Vue:

```
:items="options.name"
```

> In react i would have to do something like:

```
this.new_options = []
this.options.forEach(element => {
    this.new_options.push({
        value : element.name,
        label : element.name,
    })
})
```

And in Select:

```
                  <Select
                        name="selectedWires"
                        //closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                        components={makeAnimated()}
                        onChange={this.handleSelectChange('selectedWires')}
                        options={this.new_options}
                        isMulti
                    />
```

Comment: don't modify the array, create a copy of it in the desired format

Comment: @Sabbin yes but the select will return an `object` of the copied array, which i have to map to the corresponding object of the initial array, right?

Comment: yes you can. It depends on what functionality you have.. what do you do with the selected values?

Comment: I send them to the backend, but i need to send the original objects in order to identify them in the database, not a modified version of the same object. In the above case, i need to send `{name: 'opt1', descr:'descr1'}` and not `{value:'opt1', label:'opt1'}`. If i send the latter, i'll have to search the db and compare name with value.

Comment: So you need both `value` and `descr` in the backend? why don't you serialize that in the value, and keep the label only with the name

Comment: you could try to sent the whole object as a `value` to the backend... something like this `this.new_options = this.options.map(option=>{label: option.name , value: option}`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With `react-select` you can map options with:

```
const options = [
  { val: 'chocolate', desc: 'Chocolate' },
  { val: 'strawberry', desc: 'Strawberry' },
  { val: 'vanilla', desc: 'Vanilla' }
]

<Select
  options={options}
  getOptionLabel={(option)=>option.desc}
  getOptionValue={(option)=>option.val}
/>
```

[Docs](https://react-select.com/props#select-props)

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ayw2ut)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the index as the value, then just get the original array element in the handleChange function.

```
<Select 
    name="selectedWires"
    options={this.options.map((option, idx) => ({
        value: idx,
        label: option.name
    }))} 
    onChange={(selection, action) => this.handleChange(selection, action)}/>
```

Then in the handle function:

```
handleChange(selection, action) {
    let selectedOption = this.options[selection.value];
    ...
}
```